# Are initializer expressions part of the constructor in D?

Tags: class, d, initializer, dmd

In D, can I initialize directly on declaration and expect the initializer expressions are part of the constructor?
I came from C# and there this is the case. But with DMD 2.071.0 Im getting other behavior.

```d
class Other { }

class Test { Other nonStaticMember = new Other; }

void test()
{
    auto t1 = new Test;
    auto t2 = new Test;
    // Assert is failing, the two Test instances are 
    // being initialized to the same reference
    // instead of execute the Other constructor twice.
    assert(t1.nonStaticMember !is t2.nonStaticMember);
}
```

If this is the intented behavior it should be documented here: https://dlang.org/spec/class.html   right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code doesn't do in D what it would do in C#.

In your example, `Other` is instantiated **during compilation**.

I.e. `Other` is instantiated once, during compilation, and is placed in the program's data segment. Then, `nonStaticMember`'s initial value will, by default, point to that instance of `Other`, for all `Test` instances.

So, everything is working exactly as designed, even if it may be surprising when coming from other languages.

> If this is the intented behavior it should be documented here: https://dlang.org/spec/class.html right?

Perhaps, but note that this behavior is not at all specific to classes. A pointer to any value allocated on the heap, as the initial value of a global or local static variable, will behave the same. Whenever the value of an expression is demanded during compilation (and that includes initializers for global/static variables), D attempts to evaluate it at compile-time. A few years ago, this has been extended to allocating values on the "heap" too, which then end up in the program's initial data segment.